# anyway to find stolen device location through android device manager while location is off?

Tags: security, android-device-manager

My android device was lost few days back and now someone has it, unfortunately location setting was off on device so I can't find it through device manager but its telling me device was online 2 hours ago so it means whoever has my device he hasn't removed my google account from it, 
so is there anyway i could find the location?

Thanks

Comment: What device do you have?  See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43124/1465

Comment: I have LG G3 and that link can't help me as I don't have the device now plus no root :/

Answer (score 2):

ADM will use network based location if possible, but location services must be turned on for ADM to work. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en

Comment: I already gone through that link, unfortunately location services was off because it drains a lot of battery :( ADM should have the option to enable location settings in case device is lost :/

Answer (score 0):

If You know Your phon's IMEI number You can find your with the help of police. If they Trace The IMEI They trace your phone